# Legacy Windows application in VC++, Docker Image is built. Problem while deploying the application in Docker Swarm with Docker Service Create command

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker on Windows 10 version 1903.
I have a Legacy Windows application in VC++. 
I have built Docker image of the application and pushed to dockerhub registry. 
I have created Docker Swarm with 1 Manager and 2 worker nodes.
I am trying to deploy the application in Docker Swarm by docker service create command but following error is displayed:
1/1: no suitable node (unsupported platform on 3 nodes)

I have already created docker swarm successfully with following commandline:
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch myswitch nodename
Set manager node.

Through following command I am trying to create service on docker swarm manager node:
docker service create --network myoverylaynet --endpoint-mode dnsrr --name servicename dockerimage

**Is it possible to deploy a windows application(without GUI) to docker swarm manager node or only Linux applications can be deployed? How can I deploy my windows application to Docker Swarm?**

Answer (score 1):

I belive docker-machine creates Linux vms, not Windows vms. If you're running Win10, please see this blog post on how to create a Swarm:

https://stefanscherer.github.io/docker-swarm-mode-windows10/

Comment: Thank you @Frank for your quick response. If I create the same environment on Windows 2016 server 1607, is it possible to run Windows nodes on Docker Swarm? Is there any Windows VM specific Swarm where Windows containers can run? Please let me know.

Comment: There is, if you use Docker EE. For CE: I am not sure of Docker Desktop on Win allows you to create a swarm. You'll have to check by installing Docker Desktop and starting the swarm on the manager with `docker swarm init`

Comment: I have tested on Docker for Windows CE. `docker swarm init` on manager node with 2 worker nodes. It works like a charm. 
In docker swarm, containers communicate through Overlay network, which is an isolated network, is there any way by which containers can communicate with the host network? In Linux there is an option `docker service create --network host`. How to communicate with the Host network from containers? Is there any way out? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.